# Storing a list of used tokens in App Engine servlet - java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I have a little GAE application, a backend for my Android app.
I have a servlet in the app that pulls data from the datastore and send it to the user.
I don't want anyone to be able to use this servlet, so I store a private key in the app, and for every request I'm sending a token - a hash string of the private key and the current milliseconds, and the milliseconds I've used in the hash.
The server is taking the milliseconds and the private key, and comparing it with the token. If it went well, the server is storing the milliseconds in a `HashSet` so it will know not to use it again. (Someone can sniff the device data - and send the same milliseconds and token over and over again).

At first, I held a static field in the Servlet class, which was later discovered as mistake, because this field is not persisted, and all the data is getting lost when the instance get destroyed.

I've read about `Memcache`, but it's not an optimal solution because from what I understand, the data in the `Memcache` can get erased if the app is low on memory, or even if there are server failures.

I don't want to use datastore because it will really make the requests much slower.

I guess I'm not the first who is facing the problem.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a reverse approach in one of my apps:

Whenever a new client connects, I generate a set of three random "challenges" on the server (like your milliseconds), which I store in memcache with an expiration time of a minute or so. Then I send these challenges to the client. For each request that the client makes, it needs to use one of these 3 challenges (hashed with aprivate key). The server then deletes the used challenge, creates a new one and sends it to the client. That way, each challenge is single-use and I won't have to worry about replay-attacks.

A couple of notes on this approach:

- The reason I generate 3 challenges is to allow for multiple requests in flight in parallel.
- The longer you make the challenge, the less likely it will be that it will be randomly reused (allowing for a playback attack then).
- If memcache forgets the challenges I stored, the app's request will fail. In the failure, response I include a "forget all other challenges and use these 3 new ones: ..." command.
- You can tie the challenges to the client's IP address or some other sort of session info to make it even less likely that someone can "hack" you.
- In general, it's probably always best to have the server generate the challenge or salt for an authentication than giving that flexibility to the client.

Another approach you could use if you would like to stick with using a timestamp is to use the first request interchange to determine the time offset between your server instance and your client device. Then, only accept requests with a "current" timestamp. For this, you would need to determine the uncertainty with which you can get the time offset and use that as a cutoff for a timestamp not to be current. To prevent replay-attacks within that cutoff period, you might need to save and disallow the last couple of timestamps used. This, you can probably do inside your instance since AppEngine, AFAIK, routes requests from the same client preferentially to the same instance. Then, if it takes longer to shut down an instance and restart one (i.e. to clear your disallow cache) than your "current"-cutoff is, you shouldn't have too many issues with replay-attacks.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Your way with challenges is good, but have some overhead which I'm not sure I want to add to my servlet. I already thought on your other way (with time offset) but it leaves some space for errors. I will accept your answer because it gave me a lot of great information, but I think I will stick to my way and just use the Memcache. Thanks!